# Compose an Email with a Selected Email address in Apple Mail App

Tags: mail.app, email

I want to compose an e-mail from my Mail Application on my desktop.  I have two e-mail addresses.  How do I select one, or make sure, that the email is being sent from one e-mail address and not the other?   I'm not replying to anyone, I'm composing a new e-mail.

Thanks!

I'm attaching the form field, it doesn't show an option to select which e-mail address to send the email from?[image]

When I click the box next to orders@myemail.com, my other email address doesn't show?

Answer (score 1):

What is shown in the top part of the Mail app can be customised

[image]

Click on the box I highlighted and choose Customise. You will get a list of fields to show.

One of them is the From fields which is the one you want. Strictly with well behaved mail clients and users the Reply-To is really more relevant as that is the one a reply will be sent to However I find that some correspondants don't use it - I don't know why.

Comment: How do I customize it so it shows "From email@email.com"?

Comment: The From field will allow you to choose from all your accounts

Comment: I'm sorry, there's no option where you say it is?  I'm attaching a screen shot.

Comment: I figured it out.  I have to click on the e-mails own individual inbox to get the email address to appear as the "from".